# How do I write to a file that is in a different folder? (Python)

Tags: python, passwords, subdirectory

I am currently working on making a password program that, when prompted, will make a password and save the password in a txt file under the same name the user put. The only problem is that I don't want to have my folder all clogged up with passwords. So, I figured that the best way to get this to work is to just have a different folder inside of this same folder to hold all of the passwords:

`Password Generator ~~~(AppleWasp Password)~~~> Password Holder`

After I get this down, my problem still doesn't end as I still need to read the file later.

`Password Holder ~~~(AppleWasp Password)~~~> Password Reader`

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```py
with open("subfolder/file", "w") as fileName:

# or

fileName = open("subfolder/file", "w")
```

Comment: Although this would normally work in most scenarios, the pickle I'm in uses an input when opening the file

```newPassname = input("What site do you need a password for?\n\n")
   with open(newPassname, 'w') as newPass:```